# How did the class method call on ActiveRecord::Relation takes a context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why is this code according to the documentation works ?
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :featured, where(:featured => true)

  def self.titles
    map(&:title)
  end
end

Article.featured.titles
```

In my console gets:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Class:0xb70bfb0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial answer was the right one: it can't work...

I guess I finally convinced myself because docs should rule...

Well, I think what's important in the doc is the idea: you can chain scopes with class methods.

But the implementation of the class method given in example is definitely wrong.

Comment: I work with real data. The question is how the method map() in the Article class (Article.titles) know the context, end of chain or something.

Comment: You couldn't do `Article.titles` since you need an Array. `Article.featured.titles` is the same as doing `[article1, article2].map(&:title)`. not clear?

Answer (score 2):

If this particular behavior was the same in Rails 3.x as it is in Rails 4.x, then you can try:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :featured, where(:featured => true)

  def self.titles
    all.map(&:title)
  end
end

Article.featured.titles
```

Answer courtesy of @Nermin over in [Rails model class method for collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155085/rails-model-class-method-for-collection-of-objects) and copied here for posterity. Dupe-ish, but perhaps not since I believe the Rails versions are different.

Btw, I also filed https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21943 since this is a misleading documentation issue at best, or a bug at worst.

Answer (score 1):

This works because returned object (AR::Relation) accepts 3 kind of methods:

1) AR::Relation 'native' methods like :where, :includes, :joins, :limit, etc...

2) Enumerable methods. Most of them delegated to scoped collection, which is Array.

3) Other methods: delegated to base class through '**method_missing**'

So, API documentation in that part (chaining with class methods) is wrong :)

Comment: Really ? Please check Your console.

Comment: I mean that works as you wrote: undefined method `map' for class.. And it shouldn't return the new scope or whatever.