# Rails model class method for collection of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having trouble writing class methods to use on collections of `ActiveRecord` objects.  I've run into this issue twice in the last couple of hours, and it seems like a simple problem, so I know I'm missing something, but I haven't been able to find answers elsewhere.

Example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer

  scope :month, -> { where('order_date > ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_month.utc) }

  def self.first_order_count
    map(&:first_for_customer?).count(true)
  end

  def first_for_customer?
    self == customer.orders.first
    # this self == bit seems awkward, but that's a separate question...
  end

end
```

If I call `Order.month.first_order_count`, I get
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'map' for #<Class:...`

As far as I know, that's because `map` can't be called directly on `Order`, but needs an `Enumerable` object instead.  If I call `Order.year.map(&:first_for_customer?).count(true)`, I get the desired result.

What's the right way to write methods to use on a collection of `ActiveRecord` objects, but not on the class directly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your case, you can use a trick in this case.

```
def self.first_order_count
   all.map(&:first_for_customer?).count(true)
end
```

Will do the trick, without any other problems, this way if you concatenate this method on where clause you still get results from that where, this way you get what you need if you call this method directly on `Order`.

Comment: Perfect!  That trick is going to make things a lot easier going forward.  I never realized I could call `all` on a relation and not just on the class itself.

Comment: You, sir, are a godsend. I filed https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21943 since this is a misleading documentation issue at best, or a bug at worst.

Answer (score 6):

ActiveRecord collections are usually manipulated using scopes, with the benefits of being able to chain them and let the database do the heavy lifting. If you must manage it in Ruby, you can start with `all`.

```
def self.first_order_count
  all.map(&:first_for_customer?).count(true)
end
```

What are you trying to achieve with your code though?

Comment: I was intending to only use it chained to another scope.  Thank you for your help; I'm accepting the other answer because it was first (though only by a minute).